# I am trying to make a python list with dict items inside, to replicate a shopping list. I've written the code, but they're getting double displayed

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Here is my code

```
shop_list = [{"Apple":2}, {"Banana":6}, {"Soap":1}]

size = len(shop_list)

print("No. \t Items \t \tQuantity\n")
for i in range(size):
    for dict in shop_list:
        for key, value in dict.items():
            print("%d \t" %(i+1), "%s\t" %key, "\t%d\t" %value)
        print("")
```

I want it to be displayed like this

[image]

But it is getting displayed like this

[image]

Someone please help me with this one.

Comment: You do a loop `for i in range(size):` but inside that loop you do `for dict in shop_list:`. So every dict in `shop_list` gets printed once for every value of `i`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the index value in a 'for' loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/how-to-access-the-index-value-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: I might add that, given the way you use them (dictionaries with only 1 entry), tuples would be better than dictionaries here. Or, just use 1 dictionary with multiple keys, and get rid of the surrounding list.

Answer (score 4):

Use `enumerate` to access both the index and value instead of nesting loops.

```py
for i, d in enumerate(shop_list):
    for key, value in d.items():
        print(f"{i+1} \t {key}\t \t{value}\t")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

You put an unnecessary for loop. The outermost loop and the loop inside do the exact same thing (loop through `shop_list`). So the modified code would be:

```
shop_list = [{"Apple":2}, {"Banana":6}, {"Soap":1}]

print("No. \t Items \t \tQuantity\n")
for dict in shop_list:
    for key, value in dict.items():
        print("%d \t" %(i+1), "%s\t" %key, "\t%d\t" %value)
    print("")
```